# D3.js: real-time sunburst Partition data: recreate Hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

First off: I love D3.  It's amazing.  And makes me wish I knew JS better.  Hope someone out there can help me!

I've been working on a multi-variable, zoomable, sunburst+icicle diagram. For reference, I've been inspired by the following:

- [clickable-zoomable sunburst version shown here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst)
- [sunburst-to-icicle version here](https://bl.ocks.org/veltman/bd8d6a2f57dd8729da3437492fb9debd)
- [Mike's multi-var version here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423)
- [Kerry's ancestor sunburst here](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426)

I've recently been looking into adding a real-time component: I've integrated a real-time data feed (via MQTT) into my JS code, and it is receive/reading data from a source and adding to the hierarchical data.  Essentially, I am continually adding to the data that builds my sunburst, **redrawing the sunburst every 2 secs**, and I'm wondering the best way to do it.

Pre-real-time, I started off reading a static JSON file, using `d3.json` to load the JSON file, and then calling `d3.hierarchy` on that, which eventually I pass to `d3.partition`.  Note: because I have multiple values/variables, I need to run `partition` multiple times to get the different sized arcs, and then tween between them.  [This seemed to work fine.  Example here.](https://sg.solace.com/topic/)

But now that I'm constructing the Hierarchy + Partitions over and over, every 2 seconds, as data is loaded in from the back, I'm wondering: ***is it better to create a new hierarchy (d3 Node tree) every time from my data, or to construct the hierarchy myself?***

I'm specifically concerned about how the `select.join()` works (for tweening between the arcs of the previous and new values), and how d3 knows which Nodes are new vs. not?  If I run `d3.hierarchy()` every time, then every Node is new (right?), and so how does enter-vs-update work?  Even though the source data is the same (albeit with different values, due to real-time updates).  I don't think there's a publicly documented way of creating "new Node()", or how to maintain/add to a tree of Nodes, but seems that would be a more efficient option than running `d3.hierarchy` every couple seconds.

I hope I've explained myself clearly?  Just looking for some expert guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: I think your demo has a very fundamental problem: rendering too many elements at once. You need to start with rendering high level aggregated data and then show details on specific sectors by zoom in. A circle packing (https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-circle-packing) might be a good example for that type of hierarchical data. Collapsible tree may work as well...

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thanks for the comment. Yes, 100% agree with you, I figured that out. I ended up building in some "smarts" so that if a sector was too small (visually) to recurse down, it would "roll up" to an aggregate arc. And if you click on that, it would "enter" more detailed nodes underneath as you zoom in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.data()` you can give a second parameter that tells D3 how to identify each item.  For example `.data(mydata, d => d.data.id)` says to use the `id` field to identify each node.

Then, when `.join()` comes into play, it will look at this value and compare it to what is attached to each node.  Any new values not seen on any nodes will go to `enter`, and those values that are found on existing nodes will go to `update`.

The only trick with this is to make sure the value you specify will be definitely be unique, and won't change between calls.  For example if you do something like `.data(mydata, d => d.data.surname)` and you get two items with the same surname, the enter/update will give unpredictable results.  Likewise if you do `.data(mydata, d => d.data.randomValue)` then items will never get updated because the value will always be different between each call - the nodes will be removed via `exit` then recreated via `enter`, rather than left in place but modified by `update`, as a different value makes D3 treat them as new nodes instead of identifying them as existing ones.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! That is exactly what I ended up doing, using the 2nd parameter in `data()`.  All my elements had unique/non-changing names, and so it was super easy to find the update ones and which ones were new/entering.  Thank you!